# Boost::Asio : io_service.run() vs poll() or how do I integrate boost::asio in mainloop

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, boost-asio

I am currently trying to use boost::asio for some simple tcp networking for the first time, and I allready came across something I am not really sure how to deal with. As far as I understand io_service.run() method is basically a loop which runs until there is nothing more left to do, which means it will run until I release my little server object. Since I allready got some sort of mainloop set up, I would rather like to update the networking loop manually from there just for the sake of simplicity, and I think io_service.poll() would do what I want, sort of like this:

```
void myApplication::update()
{
     myIoService.poll();
     //do other stuff
}
```

This seems to work, but I am still wondering if there is a drawback from this method since that does not seem to be the common way to deal with boost::asios io services. Is this a valid approach or should I rather use io_service.run() in a non blocking extra thread?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Using `io_service::poll` instead of `io_service::run` is perfectly acceptable. The difference is explained in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.run_one.overload1)

> The poll() function may also be used
>   to dispatch ready handlers, but
>   without blocking.

Note that `io_service::run` will block if there's any [`work`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service__work) left in the queue

> The work class is used to inform the
>   io_service when work starts and
>   finishes. This ensures that the
>   io_service object's run() function
>   will not exit while work is underway,
>   and that it does exit when there is no
>   unfinished work remaining.

whereas `io_service::poll` does not exhibit this behavior, it just invokes ready handlers. Also note that you will need to invoke [io_service::reset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.reset) on any subsequent invocation to `io_service:run` or `io_service::poll`.

Comment: `io_service` is not necessarily stopped after `io_service::poll` returned. Why need `io_service::reset` before subsequent `io_service::run` or `io_service:poll`?

Comment: 1+ for io_service::reset. If `run` doesn't find any work, `_stopped` is set to `true` which prevents any future added tasks to be handled. `reset` sets `_stopped` back to `false`.

Comment: Yeah `io_service::reset` was referring to `io_service::run` in particular

Answer (score 4):

A drawback is that you'll make a busy loop.

```
while(true) {
    myIoService.poll()
}
```

will use 100% cpu. `myIoService.run()` will use 0% cpu.

`myIoService.run_one()` might do what you want but it will block if there is nothing for it to do.

Comment: you would indeed prefer run in this simplistic case but in the situation where an event loop already exists (say it's doing background rendering or other things in spare cycles) then poll would be preferred as you don't want the game coming to a halt every time run() blocks.

Answer (score 1):

A loop like this lets you poll, doesn't busy-wait, and resets as needed. (I'm using the more recent `io_context` that replaced `io_service`.)

```
while (!exitCondition) {
    if (ioContext.stopped()) {
        ioContext.restart();
    }
    if (!ioContext.poll()) {
        if (stuffToDo) {
            doYourStuff();
        } else {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to adjust granularity here. You picked 3 milliseconds here, but maybe that is not the right value for my application. So, this is not an universal solution.