# Boost asio http client - io_service.run()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to work out how the io_service.run() function operates in a client.  This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982595/boost-asio-io-service-run-question/1982675#1982675) but on the other end of the connection.  In a client situation there is no accept handler so when will the `io_service.run()` return?

Ideally I want to run it once (per thread, as I understand it, correction welcome, each thread that calls `io_service.run()` is basically added to the io_service thread pool) then send lots of requests without needing to call `reset`, `run` again.  There will be gaps in the requests being sent when the io_service will have no work to do but the occurrence of those gaps is largely non-deterministic, based on user behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated, an `io_service` returns when it runs out of work e.g. in a server the accept call provides it with work. To prevent an io_service from running out of work, have a look at the [`io_service::work`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) class.

This [link](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/950/entry-2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio?pg=1) taken from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244453/best-documentation-for-boostasio), provides an overview of how the work object can be used. In particular storing the work object in a `shared_ptr` and resetting the `shared_ptr` when wanting to stop the application, etc. is a useful idiom. By not calling the `io_service::stop()` method (which can also be used to stop the `io_service`) you allow all required work to be completed *cleanly*.